# VBScript Code breaking from String containing '

Tags: vbscript

one of my user has a ' inside the user name
and i think that it is breaking the login code 
on the line 
tempPassword=Request.Form("UserPassword")

```
if (Request.Form("Action") = "Login") then
    tempUsername=Request.Form("UserName")
    tempPassword=Request.Form("UserPassword")

    if not (tempUserName = "") and not (tempPassword = "") then
        strSQL="SELECT ContactID,Email,Password from Directory WHERE Email='" & tempUsername & "' AND Password='" & tempPassword & "'"
        set rsQuery=cn.execute(strSQL)
        if not (rsQuery.EOF) then
            '-- Login correct, so set session variables
            Session("CBWorkUser") = "Yes"
            Session("CBWorkUserName") = rsQuery("Email")
            Session("CBWorkID") = rsQuery("ContactID")
        end if
        set rsQuery = nothing
    end if
end if
```

what solutions is there to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation for building SQL queries. Ever. Not only will you encounter problems like this, it will also make you vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [parameterized queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190) (AKA prepared statements) instead:

```
Set cmd  = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

Set p1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@email" , 200, 1, 255, tempUsername)
cmd.Parameters.Append p1
Set p2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@password" , 200, 1, 255, tempPassword)
cmd.Parameters.Append p2

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ContactID,Email,Password FROM Directory " _
  & "WHERE Email=? AND Password=?"

Set rsQuery = cmd.Execute
```