# Update query inside Do While Not.EOF timing out

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

We have a file that runs every night which has been working for months without issue. Suddenly, it's throwing query timeout errors. A quick trace shows me that its failing every time on any secondary queries (updates).

A very generic summary of the code execution:

```vb
strSQL = "EXEC usp_GET_listofRecords"
rsRun(recSet, strSQL)
Do While Not recSet.EOF

    If recSet("condition") = 0 Then
        strSQL2 = "UPDATE t_table SET status=0 WHERE id=" & recSet("id")
        rsRun2(recSet2, strSQL2)
        rsClose(recSet2)

    ElseIf recSet("condition") = 1 Then
        strSQL2 = "UPDATE t_table SET status=1 WHERE id=" & recSet("id")
        rsRun2(recSet2, strSQL2)
        rsClose(recSet2)

    ElseIf recSet("condition") = 3 Then
        strSQL2 = "UPDATE t_table SET status=3 WHERE id=" & recSet("id")
        rsRun2(recSet2, strSQL2)
        rsClose(recSet2)

    End if
    recSet.MoveNext
Loop
rsClose(recSet)
```

This has been working fine for months and months on end, and now fails every time it hits any of the updates.

Edit: I know the update commands are valid, because doing the following works without issue:

```vb
strSQL = "EXEC usp_GET_listofRecords"
rsRun(recSet, strSQL)
Do While Not recSet.EOF

    If recSet("condition") = 0 Then
        strSQL2 = strSQL2 & "UPDATE t_table SET status=0 WHERE id=" & recSet("id") & "; "

    ElseIf recSet("condition") = 1 Then
        strSQL2 = strSQL2 & = "UPDATE t_table SET status=1 WHERE id=" & recSet("id") & "; "

    ElseIf recSet("condition") = 3 Then
        strSQL2 = strSQL2 & = "UPDATE t_table SET status=3 WHERE id=" & recSet("id") & "; "

    End if

    recSet.MoveNext
Loop
rsClose(recSet)

rsRun recSet, strSQL2
rsClose(recSet)
```

Edit 2: Including the functions called:

```vb
Function rsRun(recSet, strSQL)
    Call OpenDB()
    Set recSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    recSet.Open strSQL, dbConn
End Function

Function rsRun2(recSet2, strSQL2)
    Call OpenDB()
    Set recSet2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    recSet2.Open strSQL2, dbConn
End Function

Function OpenDB()
    Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbConn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
    dbConn.CommandTimeout = 120
    dbConn.Open strConnectionString, strUserName, strPassword
End Function
```

Comment: If this has been working before then somebody modified the script and removed the [concatenation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w) between `"UPDATE ... id="` and `recSet("id")`. However, building queries by string concatenation is bad practice anyway, b/c it opens your code to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use a [prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619736) and invoke it with the values of `recSet("condition")` and `recSet("id")` as parameters.

Comment: both TFS and the timestamp on the file show that this hasnt been touched since July 24th.

Comment: Then either the code hasn't been working or none of the conditions has been triggered since July 24th.

Comment: It has been working and the conditions have been triggered, there are email notices that are sent when this runs (didnt include those in sample), which we have been receiving every day up until 4 days ago, showing that there have been instances where each condition has been triggered. There has to be something else at play here.

Comment: So, apparently the missing concatenation operators were typos in your question ... Which statement(s) exactly are producing the error? Did you check the logs on the server side? What exactly does `rsRun2()` do?

Comment: Yes, they were. Sorry not clarifying that. All update statements will produce the timeout error. I manually updated a few records in order to hit all of the conditions. The SQL logs do not show anything other than the DB starting messages, IIS logs dont show anything, there are no windows logs that show anything from the time this task runs. I've included the functions that are called as well.

Comment: It looks like a lock issue. Another process is updating database same data at same time?

Comment: Are you running this inside a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a few issues here, but I'll get to the main cause of the timeouts first. I had my suspicions as soon as I saw calls to a function called `rsRun2`.

Notice that in your definitions for `rsRun` and `rsRun2` you make a call to `OpenDB` and open a new connection *every single time*. Calling `OpenDB` *replaces* the old `dbConn` with that new connection without closing the old one, if one was already opened. This means that with every iteration over your loop, you're opening new database connections, so as your data grows in size, you're essentially leaking* more and more connections until those connection requests start to time out because the database server won't accept any more.

The fact that your rewritten version works is further proof of this, since you're essentially working around the problem by batching up all the commands to be run in a single call on just two connections.

Note that it's perfectly okay to execute multiple commands on the same connection, so if you're only using one DB, use one connection and don't open any more. Remove calls to `OpenDB` from everywhere in your code except the very start, so you can be in full control over what you're doing.

Now for some additional advice. As Ansgar Wiechers said, your SQL is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection, especially if that's the way you write your database code elsewhere. You should look into learning how to use [ADO](https://www.w3schools.com/ASp/ado_ref_command.asp) and parameterized queries some time, to improve security in your code.

* In theory these old objects get garbage-collected by VBScript eventually, but there's no guarantee that this happens quickly or that the corresponding connection gets closed properly.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. These functions were wrote well before my time on this project. However, why would it just stop working? Regarding injection, how would be impossible for injection to occur in this instance as there are no parameters passed, and the updates are called by referencing the returned ID (primary key, auto-increment) from the sproc?

Comment: We all love legacy code! Well, the issue was clearly always there, but it's likely your database table's size only just grew large enough for this issue to become apparent i.e. the number of rows being processed, and the number of connections being left open before they timed out, exceeded the connection timeout period.

Comment: Regarding SQL injection, if that 'condition' field is an integer in the database then this particular case should be safe enough, but I'm just saying that in principle, SQL should not be strung together like this.

Comment: I also noticed that your if-statements are all virtually identical, save for the value of 'condition' each time. You could simplify the three branches into something like `If recSet("condition") >= 0 And recSet("condition") <= 3 Then strSQL2 = "UPDATE t_table SET status=" & recSet("condition") & " WHERE id=" & recSet("id")`. Again, this has the same potential SQL injection issues but it's an improvement. If you found these answers useful, feel free to accept this answer and/or give it an upvote. :)