# How to populate TextBox adding all the selected values fom a ComboList using seperated by comma so that I can use in my query

Tags: vbscript

How can I select values from a ComboList (which are filed names) to a textBox so that I can use the comma separated textbox values in my query using VBScript?

```vb
Combo1.AddItem("Field1")
Combo1.AddItem("Field2")
Combo1.AddItem("Field3")
Combo1.AddItem("Field1")
```

So I can use this in query:

```sql
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field4 FROM TableName;
```

Comment: Don't do this. *Ever.* It opens your code up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (related [xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)). *Always* use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619736).

Answer (score 0):

This will add and remove the items.

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedField As String = ComboBox1.Items(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    If (selectedField.Length > 0) Then
        If (query.Contains(selectedField)) Then
            query = query.Remove(query.IndexOf(selectedField + ","), (selectedField + ",").Length)
        Else
            query += selectedField + ","
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = query
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I am a newbie to VBScript. The above code which you provided is from .net or Vbscript because I don't get the function names as what you provided.

Comment: It is not VBscript sorry, my bad. I will see if I can write in in VBscript

Comment: What are you using for VBscript what program

Comment: The higher scenario  "need to populate data from a large size csv file and show it in excel". For this I am using VBScript and access. Is that a good go using them to do the task?

Comment: If you add both files and say what columns and data do you want. I might be able to help you.

Comment: Data is huge and too many no of Field names so thinking to dump csv data to -> access -> retrieve from access using VBA -> Generate Excel. Getting the selected Field names is from drop down and added to sql query. That query should show result and generate a excel. Is this all possible to play with a huge CSV file.?

Comment: I don't know to honest but put what you explained to me in your question up there so that others can understand what do you want. I miss understood you at first. This will help you to get an answer that fits you.