# Assist in adding logic for special character replacement

Tags: vbscript

Situation: It can be weak because of SQL Injection attack, so we received a request for securing this part.
Circumstances requiring system modification to carry out the replacement of special characters which can be used in SQL in advance.

Below is the script action logic implementation for 'special character replacement' of Click Action button which I made.

```
Public Sub Test
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, "-", "");
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, """, "");
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, ";", "");
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, ":", "");
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, "+", "");
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, "|", "");
    MyControls.txt_find.value = Myfunctions.ReplaceString(MyControls.txt_find.value, "/", "");
End Sub
```

Request: Since it has to be used in various screens, the current professional developer gave a feedback that it would be better to build a common script and use the script above when necessary.

Question: I'm in a situation where I need to program the common script and call the script above only in the necessary part.

Comment: _"the current professional developer"_ needs to get some tutorials on how to prevent SQL injection attacks. Replacing some characters by hand is not the right way... -> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: What are you using? You've tagged the question [tag:asp.net] but you speak about [tag:vbscript]. ASP.Net can use VB.Net whereas Classic ASP can use VBScript but not the other way around, they are two separate technology platforms.

Comment: Additional explanation : As client or employee impormation can be exposed in the search window, we need to replace the special characters that can be used in SQL before switching to server-side. we can limit this by adding a script from the button that operates query (on the client-side). we have come to the conclusion that we should make a common code and invoke it to apply to the needed parts on the screen.

Comment: SQL injection is a well-solved problem. Any amount of research should've given you tons of results. And I *strongly* advise you to heed to those results rather than the "conclusion" you have come to. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619736/1630171).